# Why facebook does not use public key to encrypt password before sending it to the server?

Tags: javascript, facebook, rest, security, public-key-encryption

[image]

As shown in the screen shot above facebook is showing users password in request headers.

I am just curious to know why facebook is not hiding the password using a public key.

EDIT:

Even if it is the work of HTTPS to encrypt data but HTTPS can be broken by using FIDDLER like applications.

What's wrong in encrypting the password before sending it to the server?

Comment: Isn't that what HTTPS is?

Comment: I do not why the questions got neg. points. But I Actually want to know how facebook can be so ignorant that it does not give a damn to man-in-middle attack that can be done using `fiddler` like applications.

Comment: There is no way for a web-application to stop the users from doing a man in the middle attack on himself. A 3rd-party user can not use fiddler to intercept the data without first hacking your computer to accept the fiddler root certificate

Comment: So show your amazing public-key encryption where I can't get access to the password when I have access to the browser.

Comment: @WizKid I am sorry. I am a noob and I understand what you are saying very correct and I totally agree. But I had found a github project that helps to encrypt a string (password). won't it be more secure to encrypt the password before sending it to a server. I am just asking won't it be a step more secure if we do it. https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt

Answer (score 0):

As @WizKid have commented the password is encrypted using HTTPS before it is sent from your browser, but the console you are checking it in gets the data before they are encrypted. You can try using a tool like fiddler to see what is actually sent

Comment: This is exactly what my question is. If facebook knows that HTTPS can be broken by fiddler like application then why does it not consider encrypting the password using a public key. or does facebook not know...???

Comment: In fiddler the password is encrypted and the only way to see it is if you "hack" your browser by accepting the root certificate from fiddler in your browser so the browser can accept the pub key from fiddler instead of the public key from facebook. HTTPS is based on using public key (at least to exchange keys to use for the rest of the communication)

Answer (score 0):

As @WizKid commented, the **encryption** you are suggesting in the **question** is **exactly** what **HTTPS** is doing.
**HTTPS** uses **signed certificates** that are **pre-installed** in your browser or devices, provided by **trusted third-party** certificate authorities, to **validate** the identity of the **website** and the **associated servers**. This would prevent **website phishing** and **man-in-the-middle** (MITM) attack.
The **communication** between the **users** and the **web server** is **encrypted** by **Transport Layer Security** (TLS) or **Secure Socket Layer** (SSL), so your exchanged data is protected by **MITM** attacks.
As **HTTPS** relies on **trusting** the **signed certificate**, you could decrypt the data using **Fiddler** because **Fiddler** asked you to **add** a self-generated certificate to **trust**. Without your **permission**, your data would be **safe**.

Answer (score 0):

Because HTTPS **can not be** broken by using FIDDLER like applications!

There's nothing wrong with encrypting the password before sending it to the server, it's just extra work that Facebook probably don't believe will add anything from security point of view.